# permutation arrange boys and girls in a circle

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

got the following question:

> how many ways there are to arrange 4 girls and 4 boys in a circle,
>
> with no limitations.
>
> all the boys are on one side and all the girls (**4 girls on one side and 4 boys on the other side**)
>   are on one side.
>
> every boy between two girls.

As I understand the answer to the first one is : $7!$

About the second and the third conditions I am not sure:
my strategy was:

1. arrange all the girls in a circle: $$3!$$
2. insert and rearrange the boys in the remaining spaces: $$4!$$
3. so the final answer should be: $$3!\cdot 4!$$

Is it correct?

Thanks A lot to the kind helper.

Comment: Does only the boy-girl order matter or does each individual count in the order too

Comment: every individual is unique so if Roman sits between Anna and Lena in one circle and sits between Jane and Lori in the other circle those circles are **not** the same

Comment: Your answer looks correct. There are 3! ways to arrange the girls in a circle. There are also 3! ways to arrange the boys in a circle and there are 4 possible places for Roman between 2 girls, so the answer is $3!\cdot 3!\cdot 4$

Comment: and what about the second condition?

Comment: For the second coundition, using clockwise motion, there are 4! ways to arrange the girls in a row and 4! ways to arrange the boys in a row, so the answer is $4!\cdot 4!$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your second answer is not correct.

For the first it's just  $$\frac{8!}{8}=7!$$
because there are $8!$ permutations of $8$ children and since all this happens  in the circle we need to divide by $8$.

The second problem: $$4!4!$$
Because let $a$ be all four girls and $b$ be all four boys.

Thus, we need to place $a$ and $b$ on the circle, which gives $\frac{2!}{2}=1$ cases.

Now, we can remember that they are $4$ (boys and girls), which gives $(4!)^2$.

The third problem: $$3!4!$$

For the new second problem.

If you mean that we need $4$ boys placed together or $4$ girls placed together then the answer is
$$2\cdot\frac{5!4!}{5}$$

Comment: That's exactly what I don't understand... why is this happening?

Comment: @misha312 About second? Let all girls are $a$ and all boys are $b$. We need to place $a$ and $b$ on the circle. It gives $\frac{2!}{2}=1$. Now, we can remember that they are $4$ girls and $4$ boys.

Comment: yes, I mean its again a circle so shouldn't it be the same as the third condition?

Comment: Does clockwise or counterclockwise matter? Would 132 and 123 be different?

Comment: @misha312 You miss for example the following case. Place in the circle continuously $2$ boys, $4$ girls and $2$ boys again. It's one of cases, which you want in the second problem. Your reasoning misses this case.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I think I didnt explained my self correctly the second condition dictates that on each side of the circle we have 4 girls or 4 boys

Comment: @misha312 Your new second condition is possible if it's just the third condition. Maybe you mean $4$ boys are together or $4$ girls are together?

Comment: Each possible arrangement can be reversed

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I dont quet understand what you mean

Comment: @misha312 I said many things. What do you mean? Do you mean my last words or my adding to the post?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg never mind I understand now thanks!

Comment: @misha312 You are welcome!